# How to solve "can not convert from string[] to string" error when using XGraphics

Tags: c#, arrays, string, c#-4.0, pdfsharp

I have a button for creating pdf from all images in my static directory (C:\myfolder).
but i have the error

> "can not convert from string[] to string" for the string "files" in the line below:

```
DrawImage(gfx, files, 0, 0, (int)page.Width, (int)page.Height);
```

How can i solve this error?
Thanks.
Here are my code:

```
string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\myfolder");
PdfDocument document = new PdfDocument();
document.Info.Title = "Created in Pdf";

foreach (string img in files)
{
    PdfPage page = document.AddPage();
    XGraphics gfx = XGraphics.FromPdfPage(page);
    DrawImage(gfx, files, 0, 0, (int)page.Width, (int)page.Height);
}
if(document.PageCount > 0)
{
    document.Save(@"C:\test.pdf");
}

void DrawImage(XGraphics gfx, string jpegSamplePath, int x, int y, int width, int height)
{
    XImage image = XImage.FromFile(jpegSamplePath);
    gfx.DrawImage(image, x, y, width, height);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For each `img` in your `files` list, you want to draw the `img`.
Therefore `DrawImage(gfx, files,...)` should be `DrawImage(gfx, img,...)`

Answer (score 1):

Look at your method declarations for `DrawImage`:

```
void DrawImage(XGraphics gfx, string jpegSamplePath, ...
```

The second parameter is a `string` containing the filename, not an array of `string`s.

Simply change the error in your code to use the filename (`img`) and not the filename**s** (`files`) and it will work:

```
DrawImage(gfx, img, 0, 0, (int)page.Width, (int)page.Height);
```